# Why is there attribute error on the class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, pydantic

I am trying to understand that there is a class names test_class that inherits from BaseModel. I am defining a class attribute TEST_VALUE but there is attribute error.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class test_class(BaseModel):
    """load from env"""
    TEST_VALUE: str = ""
```

If I do test_class.TEST_VALUE,
I get the following error:

```
 AttributeError: TEST_VALUE
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback value.

Answer (score 3):

Because [Pydantic's BaseModel](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/) (or likely a metaclass thereof) removes the field as it's reading your class body into a model definition.

An *instance* of that class would then have a `TEST_VALUE` instance field.

```
>>> from pydantic import BaseModel
>>>
>>> class test_class(BaseModel):
...     """load from env"""
...     TEST_VALUE: str = ""
...
>>> 'TEST_VALUE' in dir(test_class)
False
>>> 'TEST_VALUE' in dir(test_class())
True
>>> test_class.TEST_VALUE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pydantic/_internal/_model_construction.py", line 215, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(item)
AttributeError: TEST_VALUE
>>> test_class().TEST_VALUE
''
>>>
```

A class not deriving from a special (meta)class would have the class field as you expect, and the same field would be accessible via instances too:

```
>>> class test_class2:
...     TEST_VALUE: str = ""
...
>>> test_class2.TEST_VALUE
''
>>> test_class2().TEST_VALUE
''
```

Comment: How can I mock this TEST_VALUE attribute ?

Comment: You never mentioned anything about mocking in your original question. What is your end goal?